# iphone How to crop or cut UIView in curved shape sample code

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiview, calayer

How do I crop or cut a `UIView` into a curved shape?  I want to draw border to `UIView` and curved effect on corners.  I have tried with `CALayers` but the corner looks blurry, is there a another way to do that?

Comment: Show some code you've tried. Are you trying to get simple rounded corners or something more complicated? Picture?

Comment: i just want to add simple border and curved corners

Comment: this the code i m using                                                          view.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0;
    view.layer.borderColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
    view.layer.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;
    view.layer.borderWidth = 1.0f;
    view.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0.0f, 2.0f);
    view.layer.shadowOpacity = 1.5f;
    view.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor clearColor].CGColor;
    view.layer.shadowRadius = 2.5f;
    view.layer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.5f, 0.5f);
    view.layer.zPosition = 2;

Answer (score 3):

If you just want to add curve at corner of your any view or control, you can use

```
self.view.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0;
self.view.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
```

// Just need to change cornerRadius size according to your requirement.
You just have to include Quartzcore framework and import it whenever you want to get curved effect.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to include Quartzcore framework and import

**Curved effect**

```
myView.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0;
myView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
```

**Border color**

```
myView.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor redColor]CGColor];
myView.layer.borderWidth = 2.0f;
```